# Chromedriver still only supports version 79 with updated driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nunit

This is most likely a duplicate question, but in my looking around i couldnt find an answer that matches my question exactly.

I am using selenium and NUnit to run unit tests, due to circumstances I have not been working on it for a while, and now that I come back I get this error on all my chrome tests:

> OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 (SessionNotCreated)

I have updated the driver to make sure that wasn't the issue, but even using the version 83 one, I still get this same error.

Answer (score 0):

The ChromeDriver in your Windows %PATH% is likely a different version. The updated driver you downloaded needs to be saved over top of the ChromeDriver in your path.

1. Open the command prompt
2. Type `where ChromeDriver` and press Enter.
3. Save the updated ChromeDriver in the folder specified in the output of the `where` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the ChromeDriver in your project. It might be done via Tools -> NugetPages.